# Remove video on-hover controls after wanted time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

This video shows controls when hovered, and hides them when the cursor is out. How could I keep the same behaviour, but remove the controls only after the certain period of time(3 seconds) has passed..?

```js
$('#video').hover(function toggleControls() {
  if (this.hasAttribute("controls")) {
    /* setTimeout(function() {
    this.removeAttribute("controls")
    }, 3000)*/
    this.removeAttribute("controls")
  } else {
    this.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="30%" id="video">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Comment: Your code already contains a commented 'setTimeout' part. Try to move that exact code in the 'else' section instead (and uncomment it) so that a few seconds after showing the controls, they will be hidden.

Comment: tried it..get an error (setAttribute is not a function)

Comment: you're right, because 'this' has a different reference inside the setTimeout function. Try save a reference to 'this' outside of 'setTimeout' and use it inside. For example: `var thisRef = this; // and use thisRef afterwards`

Comment: oh... yeah, that = this solved it. thanks for reminding

Comment: However, it does not work when the video is playing - only when stopped, I guess that's the default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the default panel. And build your own one where you have full control. 
From my experience the change did not work properly in all browsers / devices.